# Manter o cache de uma consulta de JSON no IONIC 3

Tags: javascript, json, ionic3, service-worker

Olá, tenho um App que consome de JSON e lista os dados, até aí tudo bem.A minha dificuldade está em manter esses dados para acesso offline. Eu quero consultar depois que estiver offline.

P.S: eu estive fazendo testes com Service Worker, ele funciona perfeitamente mas no navegador, quando coloco ele no app, ele não funciona, não mantem o cache.

Gostaria de alguns links ou alguns caso de sucesso nisso.

Desde já Obrigado!

Comment: Porque não salva no localStorage?

Comment: Eu estou pensando seriamente em usar, mas quero ver alguma coisa com cache, a minha prioridade é usar cache. Pois o Aplicativo apenas consume via json, ele recebe os dados e armazena no cache. para quando não tiver rede ele busca no cache.

Comment: Bom, se achar melhor assim. Nos meus apps com ionic eu utilizo sem nenhum receio quando é para guardar informações pequenas no formato JSON. Nos que precisei guardar mais informações como blob de fotos para uso offline eu utilizei o cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Utilizar o *O Ionic Storage*:

...

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({

   ...

   providers: [
     Storage
   ]
 })


export class AppModule {}

...


import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
    constructor(storage: Storage) {

    // set        key   value
    storage.set('myKey', 'myVal');

    // get value 
    storage.get('myKey').then((val) => {

      //CASO HAJA VALOR, NAO REALIZAR CONSULTA EXTERNA
      if(val)
      //...

    })
 }
}
```